# Transcendence of values of Fredholm series at algebraic arguments

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory, transcendence

Let $d$ be an integer greater than $1$ and let $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}z^{d^n}$ be the Fredholm series. It is well-known that the Roth-Ridout theorem implies that $f(r)$ is a transcendental number for all non-zero rational $r$. By Mahler’s method, it is even true for any nonzero algebraic $r$. Can one extend the arguments of the proof based on the Roth-Ridout theorem to recover Mahler's result?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: My (limited) understanding is that Fredholm never considered such series.  Should they be named after Mahler?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the answer is no. From this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.1685.pdf), the Roth-Ridout theorem is not sufficient to establish transcendence for algebraic $r$. Indeed, it's not enough to completely cover the rational case. To obtain the same result as the Mahler's method, one should invoke the more general ($p$-adic) Subspace Theorem, as shown in the Corvaja-Zannier [paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/compositio-mathematica/article/some-new-applications-of-the-subspace-theorem/2F6BB76838F610EB90B204764335ABCA).